# How to jump to a character offset in a buffer?

Tags: vimscript, cursor-movement

Vim has the command `:goto` to go to a byte offset in a buffer.

Is there an equivalent for a character offset?  If not, is there a better way to implement it than repeatedly testing the cursor's character offset and moving backward/forward until you reach the right place?

Comment: Have you seen [this answer by Ingo Karkat on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/767963/161119)? There was also a question on the [vim-multibyte mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_multibyte/ait6hx-vhR0/Sw4qSSJrAcsJ). However, I am not sure about [the given answer by Tony Mechelynck](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_multibyte/ait6hx-vhR0/Sw4qSSJrAcsJ).

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't seen those answers, but none of them works correctly with `ff=dos` as they miscount the linebreak characters.

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me:

```
" Similar to the goto command, but for characters.
" index is 1-based, the start of the file.
function! GotoCharacter(index)
  call search('\m\%^\_.\{'.a:index.'}', 'es')

  " The search() function above counts a newline as 1 character even if it is
  " actually 2.  Therefore adjust the cursor position when newlines are
  " 2 characters.
  if &ff ==# 'dos'
    let [_whichwrap, &whichwrap] = [&whichwrap, "h,l"]
    let delta = wordcount().cursor_chars - a:index
    while delta != 0
      " Cannot land on a newline character.
      if (delta == -1 || delta == -2) && col('.') == col('$') - 1
        break
      endif
      execute "normal! ".delta.(delta > 0 ? 'h' : 'l')
      let delta = wordcount().cursor_chars - a:index
    endwhile
    let &whichwrap = _whichwrap
  endif
endfunction
```